# Why does typing three non-integers cause this function to recurse infinitely?

Tags: c++, function, recursion

I've set up a script that asks the user to input a number that's two digits long at most.

But if the user types three non-integers in, like 'fff', the recursive function `promptGetAge()` fires infinitely.

Why?

```
int promptGetAge(){
    char myString[3];

    cout<<"How old is your dog? ";
    cin.getline(myString,3,'\n');
    int userStringToInt = atoi(myString);

    if(userStringToInt==0 && !(myString=="0\0")){
        promptGetAge();
    } else {
        return userStringToInt;
    }
}

int main(){
    cout<<"Your dog is "<<promptGetAge()<<" years old!"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Once cin is in error state, you have to clean it.

Comment: Undefined behavior reading 3 chars into a 2 char buffer?

Comment: @JSF I just changed `char myString[2];` to `char myString[3];` Didn't work

Comment: ALWAYS test the result of io function, including writing to cout. `if (!(cout << "…")) throw …`, `if (!cin.getline(…)) throw …`, …

Answer (score 2):

Use the `strcmp()` function in `<cstring>` to compare content of strings, not `==` (which compares only the address of the first character).   i.e.  instead of `myString == "0\0"` use `strcmp(myString, "0") == 0`.

Or, better yet, use the `string` type in `<string>`.   Then you can use `==` for comparison.

Note that string literals have a `'\0'` character appended anyway, and `strcmp()` searches for the first one it finds.   So there is no functional difference between `strcmp(myString, "0")` and `strcmp(myString, "0\0")`

And don't use recursion to go back and repeat an action.  Use a loop.